# Can't print an alphabetically sorted array(Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

i have been having problems with a little program of mine. It's supposed to ask for words until you say nothing and then print an alphabetically sorted array from those words.Instead after i have inputed the words it prints nothing Here is the code:

```
puts "which words would you like to sort?"

def sort
  sw=[]

  word=gets.chomp.to_s

  sw2=sw.push "#{word}"

  if word == ""
    puts sw2.sort

  else
    sort
  end
end

sort
```

Comment: Please learn how to use Markdown and format your post accordingly. Alternatively, edit your question to remove the code, paste it back in raw, select the whole thing, and hit CTRL+K, which will format it for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you ask good questions (which--hopefully--will help produce good answers).

Comment: `"#{word}"` should be simply `word`. There's no reason to quote it. It should also be `sw2 << word` rather than assigning from the result of a `push`.

Comment: I tried sw<<word and it produces an error, do you have any other ideas as to how i could fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your original code:

```
def sort
    sw=[ ]
    word=gets.chomp.to_s
    sw2=sw.push "#{word}"
    if word == " "
        puts sw2.sort
    else
        sort
    end
end

sort
```

It's **great** to see someone new to code using [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).  However, some gotchas:

- What is `sw2`?
- You attempted to call the `sort` method within `sort` itself.
- You used the `==` operator to compare `word` to the string `" "`, which is ***not*** an empty answer.

Now, let's review my answer to your question:

```
def sort
    sw = [ ]

    word = gets.chomp.to_s    
    sw << word

    until word == ""
        puts sw
        word = gets.chomp!.to_s
        sw << word
        sw.sort!
    end
end

sort
```

- Notice my usage of the `until` loop, which suits your purpose and is described [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm)
- The absence of any other variables besides `word`
- The absence of any other array besides `sw`
- The use of `!` for enumerables `.chomp` and `.sort!`

I hope this helps and welcome to Ruby!

Comment: Thank you for your time as well as your answer, sw2 was my attempt to fix the former version of the code by taking the value of sw.push and assigning it to another variable. Do you mind me asking if "   " isn't an empty string what is?

Comment: @user6014992 an empty string is: `""`, while `" "` contains a space.

Comment: I have also been having a problem, the program prints the sorted array every time i input a word instead of after i input an empty string, this might be a noob question but how do i fix that?

Comment: @user6014992 Do you see that `puts sw` after the `sw.sort!` in my answer?  Move `puts sw` underneath the first `end`, still within the method `sort`.